# Select data for classification analysis, avoid causation

Tags: statistics, dataset, analysis

I just want to get a second opinion.
My problem:
I'm selecting data from different data sources to create a dataset for classification analysis. My target variable is: **failure**.

There is data from documents, which are created when a failure occurs. When there isn't a failure there is no document created.
Can I conclude any causation problem between those document data and my target variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some possibilities.

1. You do not currently know what you really want to do or you are confused about the nature of a classification problem.
2. You have all the right ideas, but you are not able to clearly communicate your question.

I think you have to think about what you want and then formulate an idea to approach that problem. You have not communicated the problem to us, so we can not really help here.

Generally, if and only if the documents (server logs?) are only created in the case of failure, than that implies causation. Because, you know, failure *causes* creation of documents.